# How to check if there is data exchange with a particular host with a script

Tags: script, ip, traffic, iftop

I have a video streaming server that streams video to many TVs.
I need to monitor the TV's remotely, so I need a tool that monitors the server network interface and say sends and email when TV A does not download D megabytes of data from the server for N seconds. iftop, bmon and iptraf do not seem script friendly applications, fix me if I am mistaken, please.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: can't agree, actually it is possible to do with iftop, will post the answer in a week.

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to use the logging features of whatever software you are using to stream. Trying to monitor the network traffic can be tricky and not always give you a clear picture of your actual activity. Most any service which is streaming video should have some sort of logs it can output, if for nothing more than debugging. Simply check the documentation for that software, and format a log which contains your desired information. Then, you could create a script or cron job which checks that output, probably filtering the data into something useful, and then pass that to the system's mail command.